# STRAPI - Relation to collections own attributes

Tags: content-management-system, strapi

I'm building a social media app, similar to Instagram and I'm trying to add pinned posts feature to the app. This feature should work so that the user can pin 3 of their posts to be shown first in their profile.

My problem is now that the user can pin any posts, even those which are not made by them. So in Strapi I want to be able to create relation to users own posts, so that they can't pin what ever post they want. Is it possible to create relation to creators own posts list, or some other way with components or collections to create this feature?

```
**In Strapi I have collections:**
**User**
- name
- description
- ...
- posts - relation to posts
- pinned - relation to posts

**Posts**
- title
- description
- ...
- creator - relation to user
```

Tried adding the pinned as relation and as component, but was not sure how to enable pinning only users own posts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use policies to determine if the user is owner of there post, and if they are then you let them pin it if not you return an error.

Here is a basic policy example:

```
export default (policyContext, config, { strapi }) => {
  if (policyContext.state.user) { 

    // you can write your logic here to check id the user that is
    // trying to pin the post is the owner if so this would return true

    // if a session is open
    // go to next policy or reach the controller's action
    return true;
  }

  return false; // if user is not the owner you would return false which would block for an unauthorized user being able to pin post that they don't own.
};
```

You can learn more about using policies [here](https://strapi.io/blog/build-a-chat-gpt-clone-with-strapi-openai-langchain-and-nextjs)

strapi docs [policies](https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/backend-customization/policies)